# Parsing Information From RSS

Tags: c#, parsing, rss

I have what I thought would be a relatively easy task at hand which is giving me lots of trouble.  I am going into a Yahoo! Weather RSS feed and trying to grab that lastBuildDate and store that value in a label.  However, when launched I get `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` in reference to the last line in the GetBuild():

```
var lastBuild = XDocument.Parse(query).Root.Element("channel").Element("lastBuildDate").Value;
```

I'm sure I'm referencing the location of the lastBuildDate incorrectly, but I'm just not sure how to fix the error.  I'm a newbie when it comes to parsing and grabbing external information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WeatherApp
{
    public partial class frmWeather : Form
    {
        string lastBuild;
        public frmWeather()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void getBuild()
        {
            string query = string.Format("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2357473");
            var lastBuild = XDocument.Parse(query).Root.Element("channel").Element("lastBuildDate").Value;
        }
        private void frmWeather_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getBuild();
            lblLastBuild.Text = lastBuild;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the format of the RSS feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
    <channel>
        <title>Yahoo! Weather - Aurora, CO</title> 
        <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Aurora__CO/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCO0019_f.html</link> 
        <description>Yahoo! Weather for Aurora, CO</description> 
        <language>en-us</language> 
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 14 Feb 2014 1:54 pm MST</lastBuildDate>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant XML snippet so I have something to write an XPath against? Also, the error doesn't indicate a problem with your path, it indicates that the data isn't valid xml.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Thanks for the reply.  You'll have to forgive me, I'm kinda new to this.  I think I'm confusing the definition of RSS and XML in my head.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Just giving my appreciation and customs & courtesies to those who take time out of their days to help with my problems.  I appreciate the reference though.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joshua RSS is an acronym for Rich Site Summary, the data is typically returned in XML format. XML is just a data format, it's used all over the place (config files, API data transfer format, ect).

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Got it. So what do you suggest is going wrong in my case?

Comment: @Joshua that I haven't figured out yet. I don't use `XDocument` regularly so I gotta do a little research on your error first.

Comment: Are you getting the contents of the web page anywhere into `query`? It looks like you're parsing the url string itself

Comment: @crennie hey good call. I don't see any `HttpRequest` being made. I think that comment is correct.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: really? I thought it was "Really Simple Syndication".

Comment: @Joshua: these sites are different from what you're accustomed to. You thank someone by upvoting their answer, not by empty, meaningless words that just clutter the question. Please _read_ the link I posted.

Comment: @JohnSaunders via Wikipedia "RSS (Rich Site Summary); originally RDF Site Summary; often dubbed Really Simple Syndication"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
 var lastBuild = XDocument.Parse(query).Root.Element("channel").Element("lastBuildDate").Value;
```

You are trying to parse a `Url` not a **XML content**.Parse method expect a `XML` content to parse. Instead use `XDocument.Load(query)`.

Or download content first then parse it:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
      string content = client.DownloadString("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2357473");
      var lastBuild = XDocument.Parse(content).Root
                     .Element("channel")
                     .Element("lastBuildDate").Value;
}
```

To avoid `NullReferenceException` use an explicit cast instead of directly accessing the `Value` property.Here is the better version with null checks:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
      string content = client.DownloadString("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2357473");
      var rootElement = XDocument.Parse(content).Root;
      if (rootElement != null)
      {
           var lastBuild = (string)rootElement.Element("channel")
                                  .Element("lastBuildDate");
           if (lastBuild != null)
           {
                 // display value in the label
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working way better than what I had going but it is returning an empty label rather then the contents in the lastBuildDate tag...

Comment: Wow `WebClient` is so much simpler than using `HttpRequest`, why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @Joshua are you sure? I tried and it worked for me.I get the date value.

Comment: @Selman22 I'm doing something wrong.  Is there anyway for me to grab your entire source?

Comment: @Joshua this is the entire source.just replace with your code and try again

Comment: @Selman22 It is kicking back WebClient()  Is this a resource or library I do not have possibly?

Comment: @Joshua add a reference to `System.Net.dll` => `using System.Net;`

Comment: @Selman22 It works! Thanks for dealing with my lack of knowledge!

Comment: @Joshua no problem.I'm glad if I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you're passing the url itself to `XDocument.Parse` rather than the results returned from doing an HTTP GET.

So you need something like this;

```
        private void getBuild()
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2357473");

            // make request and get string
            string responseBody = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            var lastBuild = XDocument.Parse(responseBody).Root.Element("channel").Element("lastBuildDate").Value;
        }
```

For the sake brevity I've omitted more of the HTTP code. Go here for a full example; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found an old test project:

```
  static void Main (string[] args)
  {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();

        doc.Load ("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?p=GMXX1791&u=c"); 
        //doc.Save ("test.xml");


        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager (doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace ("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");


        XmlNodeList lastBuildDate = doc.SelectNodes ("//rss/channel/lastBuildDate", ns);
        Console.WriteLine (lastBuildDate[0].InnerText);

        XmlNodeList nodescity = doc.SelectNodes ("//rss/channel/title", ns);
        foreach (XmlNode xnCity in nodescity)
        {
            Console.WriteLine (xnCity.InnerText);
        }

        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes ("//rss/channel/item/yweather:forecast", ns);

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}, {2}C - {3}C",
            node.Attributes["day"].InnerText,
            node.Attributes["text"].InnerText,
            node.Attributes["low"].InnerText,
            node.Attributes["high"].InnerText);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string lastBuildDate = XDocument.Parse(query).Descendants("channel").Select(x => x.Element("lastBuildDate").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```